# Magento 2: How to create easy editable collapsible content pages in magento

Tags: magento2, cms

I need some opinions to build a proper page in my `Magento` website.

The requirement is to show a `list` of `collapsible contents` in a page which in future can be easy to `edit` the `content` by the `client` itself.

My client doesn't want me to put `HTML` inside the `CMS` Page editor.

Comment: your client want only plain text to add in CMS page editor and also want collapsible the content right ? suppose there are 3 pages and they collapse like a simple accordion so will it good to your client edit the content in three different page without any HTML?

Comment: are you using bootstrap on your website?

Comment: @ManojDeswal: Yes..they want only plain text with heading and content. So when clicks on that heading the content should toggle (show & hide). Also, the page content should be maintainable means in future if they want to remove some content or need to add more collapsible contents.

Comment: @ManojDeswal: Yes we are using bootstrap. And i know we can use either magento default collapsible widget http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_collapsible.html  or bootstrap property https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#example.

Comment: @ManojDeswal: My main concern is how I should coordinate these all in Magento admin and frontend. In WordPress, i know we can create new page types and can create a new template for them also. But not idea what to do with Magento.

Comment: Yes same way,  In magento create 4 blocks and one block use HTML or Collapsible code, then call other 3 blocks which contain content in that one block ... so client only has to edit the content of 3blocks..no HTML lookup.